# Comparing cohomology of quotient by algebraic group and Borel subgroup

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, reductive-groups, equivariant-cohomology

Let $X$ a variety over an algebraically closed field $k$ (which we can assume to be actually $k=\mathbb{C}$) and $G$ a connected reductive algebraic group acting freely on $X$ (we can actually assume $G=Gl_n$). Can we relate somehow the (compactly supported) etale cohomology  $H_c(X/G,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$ and $H_c(X/B,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})$? Better

We have the morphism $f:X/B \to X/G$ which should be a fibration with fibre $G/B$ so the better possibile should be something like $$H_c(X/B,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell})=H_c(X/G,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}) \otimes H_c(G/B,\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}) $$

To get this or something similar my idea would have been to study the local systems $R^qf_*\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}$ and use the spectral sequence: $$E^{p,q}_2=H^p_c(X/G,R^qf_*\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}_c(X/B,R^qf_*\overline{\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}}) .$$ However it seems to me that there should be no reason a priori for these local systems to be trivial or the sequence to abrupt at the second page.

Comment: The compactly supported cohomology of X/G is identified with the Weyl group invariants of that of X/B.  I don't know a reference, but the "dual" statement (in Borel-Moore homology) can be proven exactly like in other homology theories where it is well-known, e.g. G-theory (Thomason "...Atiyah-Segal style") or Chow homology (Edidin-Graham "Equivariant intersection theory").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spectral sequence degenerates on the second page since $X/B \to X/G$ is a smooth projective morphism (as $G/B$ is smooth projective) by a result of [Deligne and Blanchard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray_spectral_sequence#Degeneration_theorem).

The local systems are trivial because, first, they can be trivialized on open sets $U$ where the bundle is trivial, and then on the intersection between two open sets $U \cap V$, the gluing data is given by the action of some function $U \cap V \to G$ on $H^* ( G/B, \overline{\mathbb Q}_\ell)$, but this action is trivial since $G$ is connected so the gluing data is trivial.

So there is indeed a tensor product isomorphism as you suggest (though not usually one compatible with cup product structure).

Comment: Does the theorem of Deligne-Blanchard stand without any hypothesis on $X$? (Neither smoothness or something?)

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio No, see https://cmsa.fas.harvard.edu/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/HSTAVharvard.pdf (Hodge structures and the topology of algebraic varieties by 
Claire Voisin) Theorem 3.1.